# how to fix `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'Key' in 'field list''` error in asp.net core and mysql hangfire problem?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, hangfire

i have create a cron job with asp.net core and mysql and hangfire, but when i run my project that got me an error like this `the customset table doesn't exists` so i have created a table called customset and rerun the project but that got me again an error like this `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'Key' in 'field list'`. can anyone help me?

Comment: the answer your current question is no. Provide relevant code. At the moment the only help I can give is that there is an unknown column `Key` in `field list`. Which seems self explanatory without the relevant code to look at

Comment: What is `customset`? It seems not to be related with hangfire. Do you create this dbset manaually in your dbcontext. Make sure all the fields in the `customset` exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, that error means that your entity class and the database table are out of sync. Based on the entity class, the provider is trying to select a column that doesn't actually exist on the corresponding table in the database, which means you've likely added a property to the class and didn't do a migration to propagate that change to the database.

Long and short, you need to add a migration and update your database, or if you're going with a database-first approach, fix your database so that it matches your entity class or just rerun the scaffolding.